# What, in Eclipse, modifies a project's .classpath to add the attribute exported="true" to classpathentry?

Tags: adt, eclipse-classpath

Looking at a .classpath file of a project that I inherited, I found the following difference between the committed file (to Git) and the working directory:

```
-   <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
+   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
```

If I am to revert that via the Eclipse GUI, what in the project's properties do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

[image]

The `exported="true"` or `exported="false"` in the .classpath file is determined by checking/unchecking the checkboxes that are accessible by Right-click project > Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Order and Export [tab]